# Solaris 10 sudo configuration Issue

Tags: configuration, solaris, sudo, solaris-10

I am using SunOS 5.10 Generic_147441-24 i86pc i386 i86pc

if i run

> which sudo

i get the below

> /opt/sfw/bin

when i run "sudo -l" i get the below

> User localuser may run the following commands on this host:
>
> (root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/ifconfig

for "visudo"

> visudo
>
> -bash: visudo: command not found

also /etc/sudoers file does not exist in the box.

Please help me configure sudo, how it is possible with out the sudoers file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never seen the sudo binary exist in /opt, so my first thought would be that your visudo binary is not in your path, or the sudo package you installed does not contain the visudo binary. Either way you may consider downloading the sudo package again and reinstalling.

To see if your visudo binary exists anywhere:

```
find / -name visudo -print
```

If you find nothing, remember you do not explicitly need visudo to use sudo -- it's there as a checkpoint for making sure that you do not save and exit a sudoers file that has errors, thus possibly compromising your ability to edit it again or to break sudo for all users on the host.

Also note that /etc/sudoers can start off empty, just fill it in with your sudo rules. For example, to provide sudo all commands on that host for a user without prompting for a password:

```
userid ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

That particular user ID can run "sudo -l" to list the sudo rules available to it. You could do this even just to test that sudo is in fact working on your host.

Comment: Thank you Tim for you kind help, i have updated the question with the sudo -l result.

Comment: With what you are posting, user "localuser" should be able to run "sudo ifconfig". If you want to use parameters (like ifconfig -a) you either need to specify them in the rule, or put "ifconfig *" in the sudo rule. Should work like that.

Comment: I should add that if sudo -l returns values, /etc/sudoers may not exist, but it's getting data from somewhere. Check /etc/nsswitch.conf in the sudo line, to see where it's pulling from.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you should have a look at Sun (Oracle) RBAC for accounts, rather than rely on sudo in Solaris? It is unclear from your post why you must use sudo, but if you are not calling sudo from a script, it might be worth your while to read: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1456/rbac-1.html

Answer (score 1):

You could easily get the location of the `sudoers` file from `sudo` binary itself by doing this

```
cat $(which sudo) | strings | grep /sudoers
```

Then, you would know what file to modify.

Comment: or run from root "# truss sudo". In my case found that file was: /etc/opt/csw/sudoers